# How and where can I permanently set $ program file to have extra argument '&'

Tags: bash, background-process

When I run a program from terminal like so:

```
 $ program file
```

For example

```
 $ gedit myfile.txt
```

I cannot think of a time when I would not prefer to use '&' so that I can free up my terminal for use while the program is running.

Does anyone know where or how I might set this '&' as an argument for such situations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a shell function:

```
gedit() { command gedit "$@" & }
```

or

```
function gedit() { command gedit "$@" & }
```

The `function` keyword is, in theory at least, optional. It may be necessary if the function name is already defined as an alias; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10927223/827263) for details.

The [command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-command) build-in invokes its argument as a command, bypassing any shell function of the same name.

Add the definition to your `$HOME/.bashrc` so it will be set up when you start a new shell.